# Is there an API endpoint for vimeo showcases that lets you embed a specific video within the showcase including the playlist?

Tags: api, video, embed, vimeo

I have been browsing through all of vimeo's API documentation. However, it seems there is no endpoint in the URL that lets me embed a showcase video and select a specific video of my choice. As for now, when you embed the showcase , it always starts with the first video of the showcase.

While I can get a JSON object of my showcase videos (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/showcases#get_showcase_videos), and retrieve the urls of the videos and other info, there seems to be no endpoint of embedding the video while keeping the showcase playlist on the top left (as seen here: https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/115007991707-Embeddable-Playlists).

Ideally, I'd like to keep the playlist on the top left and embed a showcase that plays a for example the second video of that showcase, determined by just changing the query in the URL.

Answer (score 4):

You can get the full showcase:
[https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/{album_id}](https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/%7Balbum_id%7D)

Get a specific video in a showcase:
[https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/{album_id}/videos/{video_id}](https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/%7Balbum_id%7D/videos/%7Bvideo_id%7D)

Or get all the videos in a showcase, so you can embed every single video:
[https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/{album_id}/videos](https://api.vimeo.com/me/albums/%7Balbum_id%7D/videos)

As you can see in the API reference:
https://developer.vimeo.com/api/reference/showcases#get_showcase_videos